# $\int_{|y|>\epsilon}\frac{|\Omega(y/|y|)|}{|y|^n}|f(x-y)|\,dy<\infty \text{ for a.e.} x\in \mathbb R^n$, where $f\in L^p$ and $\Omega\in L^1(S^{n-1})$

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

> Let $\Omega\in L^1(S^{n-1})$, where $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ for some $p\in[1,\infty)$. For each $\epsilon>0$, prove that
> $$\int_{|y|>\epsilon}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}|f(x-y)|\,dy<\infty ,\qquad\text{a.e. } x\in \mathbb R^n.$$
> Here $\Omega(y')=\Omega(y/|y|)$.

I can only prove the result for $p\in[1,\frac{n}{n-1})$.

This problem comes from the teacher of my Harmonic Analysis course. I've tried to prove
$$\int_{|x|\leq R}\int_{|y|>\epsilon}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}|f(x-y)|\,dy\,dx<\infty$$
for each $R>0$. Note: In the following I'll use $\chi_A$ to denote the indicate function of the set $A$.

\begin{align*}
&\qquad\int_{|x|\leq R}\int_{|y|>\epsilon}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}|f(x-y)|\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}|f(x-y)|\chi_{|x|\leq R}\ \ \chi_{|y|>\epsilon}\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}|f(z)|\chi_{|y+z|\leq R}\ \ \chi_{|y|>\epsilon}\,dy\,dz\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(z)|\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}\chi_{|y+z|\leq R}\ \ \chi_{|y|>\epsilon}\,dy\right)\,dz
\end{align*}

On the one hand, for each fixed $z\in\mathbb R^n$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}\chi_{|y+z|\leq R}\ \ \chi_{|y|>\epsilon}\,dy\leq\int_{\epsilon<|y|\leq R+|z|}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}\,dy\leq C\|\Omega\|_{L^1(S^{n-1})}\ln\frac{|z|+R}\epsilon.$$
This is sufficient for estimating the integral on $\{|z|\leq 2R\}$.

On the other hand, for those $z$ with $|z|\geq 2R$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}\chi_{|y+z|\leq R}\ \ \chi_{|y|>\epsilon}\,dy\leq\int_{|z|-R<|y|\leq R+|z|}\frac{|\Omega(y')|}{|y|^n}\,dy\leq C\|\Omega\|_{L^1(S^{n-1})}\ln\frac{|z|+R}{|z|-R}.$$
To ensure
$$\int_{|z|>2R}\ln\frac{|z|+R}{|z|-R}|f(z)|\,dz<\infty,$$
it suffices that $\ln\frac{|z|+R}{|z|-R}\in L^{p'}(|z|>2R)$, where $p'$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$, and this is equivalent to $p'>n$, or $p<\frac{n}{n-1}$.

However, I don't know how to prove the result for other $p$'s.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhapes just simplest holder inequality does work.Just notice that $\int_{|y|>\epsilon}\frac{|\Omega(y/|y|)|^{p'}}{|y|^{np'}}dy<\infty$.

Comment: @Mathlover Why? $\Omega$ is only in $L^1$, not in $L^{p'}$.